# Product symbol in bold

Tags: equations, symbols

why the prod command do not display bold character like in the picture below

[image]

here the code and my output

```
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript} 
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{vector} 
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{varioref} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage {minitoc} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[authory ar,comma,longnamesfirst,sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage[super]{natbib} 
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{numcompress} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabulary} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{eurosym} 
\usepackage[figurename=Fig.]{caption} 
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{stackengine}



\[
P^{\circ M,j}_{t+s\textbar{t}}(k)\equiv 
\displaystyle{\prod_{i=1}^{s}} \Pi^{\theta}_{m,t+s-i} 
\bar{\Pi}^{s(1-\theta)}_{m} P^{\circ{M,j}}(k) 
\]
```

my output

[image]

Comment: Please provide full minimal examples that we can just copy and test without having to add stuff. A lot of those packages surely have nothing to do with this issue. What exactly are you trying to do, I do not quite understand the code. `\textbar` should probably be `\bar` etc

Comment: why the \prod command do not display the product symbol in bold ??

Comment: Where are you asking it to display it in bold? Isn't the different just that you are not using the same fonts?

Comment: Please, format your code so that it becomes readable (not on a single line).

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue you say you're encountering using just the code you've posted. Are you sure you haven't got a stray `\usepackage{txfonts}` instruction hanging about somewhere in your preamble? I ask this question because I can, in fact, reproduce the second screenshot you've posted *if* I also load the `txfonts` package.

Comment: @daleif - Weirdly, `\textbar{t}` is equivalent to `\mid t`. Don't ask...

Comment: @Mico `\textbar` is illegal in math mode, but it produces a vertical bar, what else?

Comment: @egreg - I was merely addressing @daleif's conjecture that `\textbar` might/should be replaced with `\bar`. :-)

Comment: @Mico I think it should simply be `\mid`, in that case

Comment: @egreg - Indeed, `\mid` is what I used in the answer I posted a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following package `\usepackage{bm}` and code with `\bm` with required symbol like below:

```
\[
P^{\circ M,j}_{t+s\textbar{t}}(k)\equiv \displaystyle{{\bm\prod}_{i=1}^{s}} \Pi^{\theta}_{m,t+s-i} \bar{\Pi}^{s(1-\theta)}_{m} P^{\circ{M,j}}(k) \]
```

Comment: `\textbar` isn't appropriate in math mode; use `\mid` instead. Separately, the `\displaystyle` directive is both unnecessary and applied incorrectly: it's a switch, i.e., it doesn't take an argument.

Answer (score 2):

You could also always try `\mathbb{\Pi}`, thats what I usually use. Requires `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Comment: Your suggested approach is going to create no end of confusion between the `\Pi` symbols already present in the equation and the (bold) product symbol.

Answer (score 2):

In order to reproduce the screenshot with the objectionable-looking product symbol, it appears to be essential to load the `txfonts` font package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\begin{document}
\[
P^{\circ M,j}_{t+s\mid t}(k) \equiv \prod_{i=1}^{s} \Pi^{\theta}_{m,t+s-i} 
\bar{\Pi}^{s(1-\theta)}_{m} P^{\circ{M,j}}(k) 
\]
\end{document}
```

If `txfonts` is *not* loaded, the following look is generated:

[image]

Note that the `\prod` symbol is *not* rendered in **bold** in either screenshot. It's just naturally "darker" when using Computer Modern fonts.

Incidentally, you shouldn't use `\textbar` in math mode; use `\mid` instead.

If you *must* use Times Roman text and math fonts in your document but simply can't stand the look of the `\prod` symbol that's generated by either the `\txfonts` or the `\newtxmath` font packages, consider using either the `mathptmx` or the `mtpro2` packages. (Aside: the full `mtpro2` package isn't free of charge; however, its "lite" subset, which is all that's needed for the example code at hand, is indeed free.)

Comment: thanks a lot,it works now ,  your comments are always useful.